# What is the "<Module>" type?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, cil, mono.cecil

I am using Mono.Cecil to read an assembly generated by `Regex.CompileToAssembly()`. When I iterate through the types, there is one type in the root namespace named `<Module>`. The type has no base type. What is this type? Is this some Mono.Cecil artifact or something that is actually a real part of .NET assemblies? What role does it play?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<Module>` type is a place-holder for declarations that do not fit the CLI model.  Normally relevant only in assemblies that are mixed-mode, containing both code written in a managed language as well as an unmanaged one like C or C++.  It is empty for pure managed assemblies.

Those languages support free functions and global variables.  The CLR does not directly support that, methods and variables must always be a member of a type.  So the metadata generator uses a simple trick, it creates a fake type to be the home of such functions and variables.  The name of that fake type is `<Module>`.  It always has *internal* accessibility to hide the members.  There is only ever one of those types, its RID is always 1.

The CLR source code calls it the "Global Class".